# YAGO TTL to Local Virtuoso Instance

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, virtuoso, linked-data

I am trying to load the YAGO ontology to a local instance of Viruoso database. YAGO is available [here](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/databases-and-information-systems/research/yago-naga/yago/downloads/) in 7zip format. However, using the online gui I am unable to load the 7zip file. Using the terminal I am still unable to load the db. However, if I extract a specific ttl file from the 7zip file I am able to load it using both ways. What is the problem with the full 7zip file?
In addition what prefix should I use as third parameter in the ld_data command?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, currently Virtuoso only supports gzip compression format. So one option would be to use the [Bulk Loading RDF Source Files](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtBulkRDFLoader) features of Virtuoso with the extracted files. For example, you can load all the files using

```
> isql
SQL>  ld_dir ('/path/to/extracted/files', '*.ttl', 'http://graph.name');
SQL> rdf_loader_run();
```